# A SQL query to get the last status for a file uploaded possibly using a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, postgresql, subquery

I need to write a query which I think will need a subquery in it. Currently I'm writing the query as a raw SQL statement using DataGrip and will need to work on a postGres server. I am using Laravel to write the application in which this query needs to work in.

The two tables needed to write the query are **media_files** and **statuses**. There is a link between the 2 tables:
media_files.id = statuses.model_id

Files are stored in **media_files** and can have two statuses which are **pending** and **attached.** The statuses for files are stored in **statuses**. The **statuses** table can also contain statuses of other things such as tasks, events, users, etc.

I need a way of getting all the files where the last status for them is **pending.** Some files may not even have a **pending** status and these can be ignored.

The statuses table can hold multiple statuses of the same media file. So for example you can have:

**Record 1**

media_files.id = 1

media_files.name = 'CV document'

statuses.id = 2

statuses.model_id = 1

statuses.model_type = 'App\MediaFile'

**statuses.name = 'attached'**

statuses.created_at = '2020-06-16 17:39:08'

**Record 2**

media_files.id = 1

media_files.name = 'CV document'

statuses.id = 1

statuses.model_id = 1

statuses.model_type = 'App\MediaFile'

**statuses.name = 'pending'**

statuses.created_at = '2020-06-14 17:30:00'

I have made a start on the query but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
select media_files.*, (
    select name
    from statuses
    where model_id = media_files.id
      and model_type = 'App\File'
    order by statuses.created_at desc
    limit 1
)
as latest_status
from media_files
inner join statuses on statuses.model_id = media_files.id
where statuses.model_type = 'App\Entities\Media\File'
order by media_files.id desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to determine if the last pending status is the last status:

```
select mf.*
from media_files mf join
     (select s.model_id,
             max(case when s.status = 'pending' then s.created_at end) as last_pending_created_at,
             max(s.created_at) as last_created_at
      from statuses s
      group by s.model_id          
     ) s
     on s.model_id = mf.id
where last_pending_created_at = last_created_at;
```

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select mf.*
from (select mf.*,
             (select s.status
              from statuses s
              where s.model_id = mf.id
              order by s.created_at desc
              limit 1
             ) as last_status
      from media_files mf
     ) mf
where last_status = 'pending';
```

Comment: Gordon, that's brilliant. I really appreciate your help. The first query runs much quicker so I'll be using that one. 


However it isn't working exactly as I want it to although it is almost there. In some instances there can be two records in the **statuses** table for the same file and the **created_at** column value can be exactly the same - the only difference would be the actual status where one would be 'pending' and the other would be 'attached' - is there a way in this scenario to order by the **id** column value as I'm using the auto increment on the **id** column.

Comment: @Riz . . . If the `id` column is really capturing the ordering, use that instead of `created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an analytic function as well

```
SELECT MEDIA_FILES.*,LATEST_STATUS.* 
FROM 
(SELECT NAME,MODEL_ID,
MAX(CREATED_AT) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME) AS MAX_TM
WHERE MODEL_ID = MEDIA_FILES.ID
AND MODEL_TYPE = 'App\File') AS LATEST_STATUS,MEDIA_FILES
WHERE LATEST_STATUS.MODEL_ID=MEDIA_FILES.MODEL_ID
```